# mongoose skip doesn't skip docs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to iterate over my collection that contains ~31k docs.
each time I want to query to return 100 docs using `skip` to start from the first doc and return the next 100 and so on.
I am getting the `skip` index from the request:

```
find: function (req, res) {
            var name = "node"
            var limit = 100;
            console.log(req);
            var query = {};
            query = req.query;
            var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
            var query = url_parts.query;
            console.log("skip typeof : " + typeof(Number(query.skip)));
            var Collection = getCollection(name);
Collection.find(query).skip(Number(query.skip)).limit(limit).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                console.log(docs);
                res.send(docs);
            });

            });
```

the console logs shows that `query.skip` : 1, 101 , 201 ... so the problem must be in my query:

```
Collection.find(query).skip(Number(query.skip)).limit(limit).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                console.log(docs);
                res.send(docs);
            });
```

but the docs that the query returns are the same for each request:

```
req 1 [{nid : 4033},{nid:4501}]
req 2 [{nid : 4033},{nid:4501}]
```

skip value is Number :

```
skip typeof : number
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the same query on the mongo console?

Comment: I will post the result.

Comment: works fine in mongo console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that `query.skip` is a string, and MongoDB wants it to be a number:

```
Collection.find({}).skip(Number(query.skip)).limit(...)
```

**EDIT**: apparently, you're passing `query` to `find()` as well, which won't work if `skip` is also a property (as MongoDB will consider that to be a query field).

Try this:

```
var skip = Number(query.skip);
delete query.skip;
Collection.find(query).skip(skip).limit(...);
```

Comment: No, when I console log type of its Number.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I don't see how it can already be a number, as you're using `url.parse()` to get it. AFAIK, that function will always return strings. So perhaps you're not posting all your code? For a quick check, just use a hardcoded value passed to `.skip()` to see if that works.

Comment: It was a string you are right, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is it have any connection to index's? should I index the collection?

Comment: If you log `typeof(Number(query.skip))`, it will obviously always be a number. You need to make sure that you pass the value as a number to your query (your posted question now contains two distinct versions of the query). You don't need an index for `skip()` to work.

Comment: I just console log all the values, they are all Number. it works fine in my mongo console if it matters.

Comment: Now you're posting `Collection.find(query).skip(Number(query.skip))`. Since `skip` is part of `query`, this obviously isn't going to work...

Comment: but the Number function are turning it to Number.

Answer (score 0):

So like the comments say I use:

```
var skipInNumber = Number(query.skip);
```

and the query :

```
Collection.find(query).skip(skipInNumber).limit(limit).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                console.log(docs);
                res.send(docs);
            });
```

credits goes to the comments dude.